# boto3: can't find queue that was immediately created before

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-sqs

I create an SQS queue in boto3 and immediately look for it via `sqs.list_queues` but it won't return anything.

when I input the SQS queue name into the console, it won't return anything until I input it again the second time.

So does this mean I need to call list_queues twice? Why is this happening? Why isn't AWS return queues that was immediately created before?

```
    sqs = boto3.client('sqs')
    myQ = sqs.create_queue(QueueName='just_created')

    response = sqs.list_queues(
        QueueNamePrefix='just_created'
    )
```

`response` does not contain the usual array of `QueueUrls`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like many AWS services, SQS control plane is eventually consistent, meaning that it takes a while to propagate the data accross the systems.

If you need the URL of the queue you just created, you can find it in the return value of the `create_queue` call.

The following operation creates an SQS queue named MyQueue.

```py
response = client.create_queue(
    QueueName='MyQueue',
)

print(response)
```

Expected Output:

```
{
    'QueueUrl': 'https://queue.amazonaws.com/012345678910/MyQueue',
    'ResponseMetadata': {
        '...': '...',
    },
}
```

Comment: hmmm actually what I'm doing is creating a queue in one HTTP request and then in a separate HTTP request fired immediately after it, needs to list all the queues with specified prefix. Basically the 2nd HTTP request needs a complete list of all queues with specified prefix. I guess I have no choice but to store the QueueURL immediately after creating it and then reference it in the 2nd HTTP endpoint that calls `sqs.list_queues`!

Comment: the other thing is that even after waiting 5 seconds via `time.sleep(5)` in between those two calls still results in an empty list of QueueUrls. When I set it to 30 seconds, it works! so I guess I need some sort of a while loop that will attempt list_queues` every few seconds until it returns something.

Comment: what is the return code of `create_queue` ?  Do you check it ?  Is it succesful ? and what about testing with CLI "aws sqs list-queues" does it return the same ?  Be sure to drop your filtering parameter at first in case you get it incorrect.  Only when you will see the queue, try to apply the filtering logic again

Comment: after waiting 30 seconds it lists the queue. im gonna have to write a poller that repeatedly calls `list_queues` until it returns the queueurls I want